# Docker, proper way to create network for two containers

Tags: docker

In regards to docker inter-communication.

Given that the `--link` flag is deprecated (so I read) and the preferred way is to create a new networks, like:

```
docker network create my_network
```

And then let the two containers be created with `--network my_network`, i.e.:

```
docker run --name container1 --network my_network -d iamsecret -p 1234:1234
docker run --name container2 --network my_network -d iamawebserver -p 80:80
```

How can I achieve:

1. Specify which subnet and which IPs are assigned **statically** to the network and my two containers (so I can reference them in code). For example let's say I want my network to use `172.16.23.0`; `container1` is `172.16.23.2` and `container2` is `172.16.23.3`.
2. Allow `container1` to be talked to only by `container2` (like it it were a db)
3. Allow `container2` to talk to `container1` but at the same time be reachable by my pc (like if it were a webserver).

Thanks

Comment: I remember myself asking something similar about a year ago... It was never answered: [docker - network configuration to isolate two containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322830/docker-network-configuration-to-isolate-two-containers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found a way, but I am sure there is a simpler and more elegant way. Credits go to http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/docker-networking-101/

```
#start containers attached to bridge default network, both open at this point
docker run --name container1 --network bridge ...
docker run --name container2 --network bridge ...

# create new internal network with my ips
docker network create --internal --driver=bridge --subnet=172.16.23.0/24 --gateway=172.16.23.1 mynet

# disconnect secret host from public bridge
docker network disconnect bridge container1

# connect containers to secret network with my chosen ips
docker network connect --ip 172.16.23.2 mynet container1
docker network connect --ip 172.16.23.3 mynet container2
```

Please, do add your answer if you think there is a better way or something above is wrong!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use docker-compose.

You need a docker-compose.yml file (see example below) and it will create the network as per the last section, build the images as per the first 2 sections, maps container ports to network ports and then attaches the containers to the network.

```
version: '3'

services:
  container1:
    image: container1
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5100:80"
    depends_on:
      - container2
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.1.10
  container2:
    image: container2
    build:
      context: ./container2
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5200:80"
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.1.20
networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      -
        subnet: 172.16.1.0/24
      -
        subnet: 2001:3984:3989::/64
```

Once you've got your docker-compose file set up, you run it with:

```
docker-compose up
```

To take it down:

```
docker-compose down
```

To force it to rebuild your images (if built before it will use existing image):

```
docker-compose up --build
```